# How to monitor Xerox printer jobs?

Tags: monitoring, snmp, printer

I'm trying to write a system for monitoring around 200 network printers using SNMP (Java SNMP4J library). The printers are mainly Xerox Phasers and Workcentres.
Now, I need to get:

1. the number of pages printed
2. the print quality settings that was used (if it's possible).

I think I will need to use SNMP traps to get this information.

I have a Xerox WorkCentre 6015NI at my disposal, I configured it to send SNMP traps to my laptop, but the only traps I have received so far are those about starting up - I get no traps when a page is printed.

So my questions are:

1. Are SNMP traps the right way to get the required info?
2. Is it necessary to subscribe for a specific trap (somehow) or the printers should send all traps generated (when my computer is in the list of SNMP trap receivers).
3. Are there Xerox MIBs/OIDs for job monitoring traps that should work on all or most their printers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It depends on whether a trap has been defined for 'page printed' or 'job printed'.  Looking at my kyoceria printer/copier, traps are generated only for errors (jams, paper out, low toner, etc), not for normal operation.   Even so, I prefer polling for counters.  You get more information (like the printer is offline), and you control how often you are polling. Traps are not guaranteed to tell you the printer is turned off.
2. If you have a trap receiver on your computer, you should only need to specify a trap destination on the printer.  YMMV, check your printer's configuration.
3. [Mibdepot](http://www.mibdepot.com/cgi-bin/vendor_index.cgi?r=xerox) has xerox printer mibs.  But I'd check with Xerox for model, latest, etc.  Looking over the Xerox mibs on Mibdepot, you should be able to [poll for job quality.](http://www.mibdepot.com/cgi-bin/vendor_index.cgi?r=xerox)